# Laravel - How to treat different status code as count

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use Larave-5.8 for chartjs pie chart with a field status_code

```
$status_record = EmployeeApplication::selectRaw('count(status_code) as count,status_code, if (status_code = 1, "Pending", "Treated") as status')->whereNotIn('employee_code', $publishedgoals)->where('hr_response', 0)->groupBy('status_code')->get();
```

The code I have written on works for two items

status_code is tinyint which can have 0,1,2,3

I want it to add all these

1. 0 = Draft
2. 1 = Pending
3. 2 = Treated
4. 3 = Untreated
5. count of the whole field in the table = TotalSubmitted

How do I modify

> selectRaw('count(status_code) as count,status_code, if (status_code = 1, "Pending", "Treated") as status')

in the code above to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

### [`Case`](https://www.sqlshack.com/case-statement-in-sql/)

which returns a value on a **specified** condition, In your case (no pun intended) it returns the status of `status_code`.

---

```
$status_record = EmployeeApplication::selectRaw('count(status_code) as count,CASE
         WHEN status_code= 0 THEN \'Draft\'
         WHEN status_code= 1 THEN \'Pending\'
         WHEN status_code= 2 THEN \'Treated\'
         WHEN status_code= 3 THEN \'Untreated\'
         ELSE \'TotalSubmitted\'
    END as status')
->whereNotIn('employee_code', $publishedgoals)->where('hr_response', 0)
->groupBy('status')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$status_record = EmployeeApplication::whereNotIn('employee_code', $publishedgoals)->where('hr_response', 0)->get()->groupBy('status_code')->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->count();
});
```

Comment: How do I bring out those values in 

    0 = Draft

    1 = Pending

    2 = Treated

    3 = Untreated

    count of the whole field in the table = TotalSubmitted
  because i want to represent the 0,1,2,3 with the values in my chart