# How to implement IF Statement for more than two Parameters in Eloquent

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 5.8 project, I have this query:

```
$approval_record = HrEmployee::selectRaw('count(is_approved) as count,is_approved, if (is_approved = 1, "Awaiting", "Approved") as approval')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->groupBy('is_approved')->get();
```

In my DB, is approved has 1, 2 and Any other number.

1 is Awaiting, 2 is Approved, then any other number?

How do I modify the IF statement in my code above to achieve this?

Comment: Why not use `case` like yesterday's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62683144/laravel-how-to-treat-different-status-code-as-count)?

Comment: You can use `Case` for this scenario.

Comment: @Makdous - Some have null values and its not counting them. what do I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to this [article](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-use-if-condition-in-laravel-select-queryexample.html)

you can use case:

```
 $approval_record = HrEmployee::selectRaw('count(is_approved) as count,is_approved,
          (CASE COALESCE (is_approved, 0) WHEN  "1" THEN "Awaiting" WHEN  "2" THEN "Approved"
WHEN "0" THEN "empty"  ELSE "somethingElse" 
              )as approval')
                ->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->groupBy('is_approved')->get();
```

Comment: Some have null values and its not counting them. what do I do

Comment: I did as you advised, but still the same issue

Comment: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27845658/10573560 you could use when COALESCE